# How to refactor <List> contents using the map() method in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

*Note: An (optional) CodeSandbox demo as part of the answer would be most helpful*

I want to refactor a list in JSX. Specifically, I [started with this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3zokkyxx3). Now I want to [refactor it into this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3j56vxx8m). But I keep getting the following error.

> ```
> /demo.js: Unexpected token (17:7)
>   15 |   <ListItem key={`${label}`}>
>   16 |     <ListItemIcon>
> * 17 |       <`${icon}` />
>      |       ^
>   18 |     </ListItemIcon>
>   19 |     <ListItemText primary={`${label}`} />
>   20 |   </ListItem>
> ```

Or, in other words.

To this (throws error) | https://codesandbox.io/s/p3j56vxx8m

```
import React from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";

const list = [
  { label: 'Inbox1', icon: InboxIcon },
  { label: 'Inbox2', icon: InboxIcon },
  { label: 'Inbox3', icon: InboxIcon },
];

const constructListItem = (label, icon) => (
  <ListItem key={`${label}`}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <`${icon}` />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary={`${label}`} />
  </ListItem>
);

class Dashboard extends Component {

  state = {
    list: list
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List component="nav">
        {this.state.list.map((item) => (
          constructListItem(item.label, item.icon);
        ))}
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleList;
```

From this | https://codesandbox.io/s/k3zokkyxx3

```
import React from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";

function SimpleList(props) {
  return (
    <List component="nav">
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox1" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox1" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox1" />
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
}

export default SimpleList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a few things wrong with your sandbox example, but I've fixed it for you. Add the contents of the below to `demo.js`.

You can use `React.createElement(icon)` to achieve this behaviour.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";

const list = [
  { label: 'Inbox1', icon: InboxIcon },
  { label: 'Inbox2', icon: InboxIcon },
  { label: 'Inbox3', icon: InboxIcon },
];

const constructListItem = (label, icon) => (
  <ListItem key={`${label}`}>
    <ListItemIcon>
    {
      React.createElement(icon)
    }
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary={`${label}`} />
  </ListItem>
);

class Dashboard extends Component {

  state = {
    list: list
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List component="nav">
        {this.state.list.map((item) => (
          constructListItem(item.label, item.icon)
        ))}
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Some problems:

- Semi-colon included after `constructListItem` (within your map function) doesn't need to be there.
- `Component` was undefined
- You're exporting `SimpleList` but it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872883/5403618), here is my version of the fixed code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";

const list = [
  { label: 'Inbox1', icon: <InboxIcon /> },
  { label: 'Inbox2', icon: <InboxIcon /> },
  { label: 'Inbox3', icon: <InboxIcon /> },
];

const constructListItem = (label, icon) => (
  <ListItem key={`${label}`}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      {icon}
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary={`${label}`} />
  </ListItem>
);

class SimpleList extends Component {

  state = {
    list: list
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List component="nav">
        {this.state.list.map((item) => (
          constructListItem(item.label, item.icon)
        ))}
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleList;
```

Comment: Thanks. Also helpful. I was wondering how to get `{icon}` to work. Which you solved.  Quick question, why does `{icon}` work without the backticks? But I need them for `${label}`?

Comment: Oh, wait. After double checking it, it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: The reason is, in JSX anything inside `{  }` needs to be a valid javascript expression. You don't need backticks for `${label}` as well. `<ListItemText primary={label} />` would work too.

Comment: The only issue with using `{icon}` is that you cannot pass props (or children) to the icon.

Comment: @Dan, Completely agree!